# Steam Username not showing while using grschafer's Steam OpenID and WebAPI with Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, steam-web-api

I am trying to get the Sign In Through Steam to work while using Ruby/Rails.

I am currently using the c9.io ide.

Here is the [link](http://grschafer.com/guides/2013/09/07/steam-openid-and-webapi-with-rails/) to the tutorial that I am following.

So far, I got to the end of the tutorial without any errors, but once redirected to the home page, it only says "Current user:", without the username used for the login.

Here's [what the console says](http://pastebin.com/GtpH6tHa) while logging in.

The following is the main piece of code that is supposed to get the username. It uses the gem 'omniauth-steam'.

```
def auth_callback
auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
session[:current_user] = { :nickname => auth.info['nickname'],
                                      :image => auth.info['image'],
                                      :uid => auth.uid }
redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @KirsKringle and anyone else, I do not remember how I managed to do this, but if you want to see my conversation with grschafer himself, please comment your email and I will forward our conversation from 2015 to you!